# ASP .NET Core 2.0 deployment unable to connect with WCF service in production

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I have a .NET core app in that has connected WCF Service, everything works fine in the dev environment, but in the deployment environment the service is not connecting.
I published the ASP .NET core project and hosted it in IIS, the published app also contains the ConnectedService.json file:

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.20628.921",
  "GettingStartedDocument": {
    "Uri": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858517"
  },
  "ExtendedData": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:8759/Design_Time_Addresses/CECWcfServiceLib/CECService/text/mex",
    "Namespace": "CEC_WCF_Service",
    "SelectedAccessLevelForGeneratedClass": "Public",
    "GenerateMessageContract": false,
    "ReuseTypesinReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "ReuseTypesinAllReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "CollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Array",
      "Item2": "System.Runtime.dll"
    },
    "DictionaryCollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2",
      "Item2": "System.Collections.dll"
    },
    "CheckedReferencedAssemblies": [],
    "InstanceId": null,
    "Name": "CEC_WCF_Service",
    "Metadata": {}
  }
}
```

The error I get is

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AspNetCore.Views_Home_CEC_Dashboard.ExecuteAsync() in D:\Users\sajja\source\repos\CECDashboard\CECDashboard\Views\Home\CEC_Dashboard.cshtml:line 9
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Am I missing a deployment configuration because this works fine in dev environment.

[**Update**] Code in the HomeController

```
public ActionResult CEC_Dashboard()
        {
            try
            {
                CEC_WCF_Service.CECServiceClient cECService = new CEC_WCF_Service.CECServiceClient();
                var task1 = Task.Run(async () => await cECService.OpenAsync());
                task1.Wait();

                var task2 = Task.Run(async () => await cECService.GetAccountsAsync());
                task2.Wait();
                var accountsInfo = task2.Result.ToList();

                var task3 = Task.Run(async () => await cECService.GetAccountStatsOnAccountAsync(1));
                task3.Wait();
                var account_Stats = task3.Result.ToList();

                ViewData["Account_Stats"] = account_Stats;
                ViewData["accountsInfo"] = accountsInfo;
                ViewData["DefaultAccountsView"] = accountsInfo.Find(o => o.AccountId == 1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Based on `ConnectedService.json`, it connects `http://localhost:8759`. Have you published your WCF Service or run WCF Service under `http://localhost:8759`? In addition, for this error, it happens in `Home\CEC_Dashboard.cshtml:line 9`. Share us more information about it.

Comment: Yes, the WCF service is running and I can navigate to the page as well. The error that's happening is because at the page startup in the HOME controller I'm calling the function to fetch info from the WCF service to be displayed on the page. I've added the code I'm calling in the original post. By the way all this works in dev environment, but somehow breaking in production.

Comment: For this error, it seems one of `ViewData["Account_Stats"]`, `ViewData["accountsInfo"]`, `ViewData["DefaultAccountsView"]` is null. Try to log the value for them. In addition, your exception is thrown by view, try to add null check before you access them in the view.

Answer (score 1):

So, after days of research I figured out the problem. As originally thought, the problem was indeed related to the WCF configuration for production deployment.

So, here is what I did after research on multiple threads.

1- Injected IConfiguration in HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;

        public HomeController(IConfiguration iConfig)
        {
            configuration = iConfig;
        }
  <...More Class Code here ...>
 }
```

2- Added the settings in appsettings.json

```
"MyService": {
    "EndpointUrl": "http://localhost:8082/hello?wsdl"
  }
```

3- Here is what was missing while doing production deployment. The Reference.cs file has the address of the dev time address, so I did all the above to mitigate and be able to load the production address at run time.

This method is referred in one of the post [Reference Post](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3070)

```
//
                var EndPoint = configuration.GetSection("MyService").GetSection("EndpointUrl").Value;
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                //

                CEC_WCF_Service.CECServiceClient cECService = new CEC_WCF_Service.CECServiceClient(result, new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(EndPoint));
                var task1 = Task.Run(async () => await cECService.OpenAsync());
                task1.Wait();
```

This resolved the issue for production deployment!